# -fno-exceptions for some libraries?

Tags: c++, exception, stl, g++, compiler-flags

This is somewhat similar to "[Disabling C++ exceptions, how can I make any std:: throw() immediately terminate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249378/disabling-c-exceptions-how-can-i-make-any-std-throw-immediately-terminate)." I would like my program to terminate whenever an exception is thrown out of the STL.

The problem is as follows: I am writing a library which is then loaded as a shared object and executed by a program I don't have control over. Unfortunately this program runs everything in a big try bock so that I don't get a stack trace/core dump if an error is thrown, rendering the `::at` class of function's out of range error useless.

This sounds like the ideal use case for -fno-exceptions, but I can't just use -fno-exceptions, because boost_log and the program that calls me both have exception handling defined in their headers giving me compile errors with -fno-exceptions.

**Is there a way to enable -fno-exceptions only for stl exceptions?**

Comment: In libstdc++, if `at` detects an argument out of range, it calls `void std::__throw_out_of_range(char const*)`. If you define your own function with the same name and arrange for it to be picked at link time (LD_PRELOAD may be easiest for an experiment), you should be able to change the behavior to whatever you like.

Comment: The "STL" as a separate library pretty much stopped existing in 1998; there really is no such thing as "STL exceptions" in todays C++. Much of the current library can be traced back to Boost instead of the STL. (And of course, quite a few compiler vendors have reimplemented these classes)

Comment: If you are doing C++11, you could mark your function as `noexcept`, so if an exception tries to escape it, the program will be immediately terminated.

Comment: @MarcGlisse it seems `noexcept` is really the best solution in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With C++11, the easiest way to do is to add `noexcept` to the signature of the top level function that is called from your shared library:

```
void called_func() noexcept;
```

This will cause any unhandled exceptions in the `called_func` stack frame (or below if they are not handled) to terminate the execution of the program.