# C++: error: exception handling disabled, use -fexceptions to enable

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to compile simple code with -fno-exceptions flag. Its giving error.

Please let me know how to suppress this. I am using gcc version 4.6.3

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
  try
  {
    throw 20;
  }
  catch (int e)
  {
    cout << "An exception occurred. Exception Nr. " << e << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**Log**

```
> g++ throw.cc -o out -fno-exceptions
throw.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
throw.cc:10:11: error: exception handling disabled, use -fexceptions to enable
throw.cc:14:56: error: ‘e’ was not declared in this scope
```

**Edit**

I have a client code which have lot throws like this. I have to integrate this in my project and I can't control compilation flags to build(which will come from config which has -fno-exceptions enabled). I wanted a quick work around that I can suggest.

**EDIT**

I found a workaround see below for my answer.

Comment: Why did you compile with `no-exceptions` when your code is clearly designed to catch an exception?  Why don't you follow the compiler's suggestion, and change to `-fexceptions`?

Comment: this is a simple program i wrote to illustrate here. I have a test setup which uses -fno-exceptions flag and .so file which use throw internally.  I cant change the -fno-exception in my test setup, cos it is not controlled by me. And I cannt change the .so either. so the question

Answer (score 19):

You cannot use `-fno-exceptions` flag with program, that use exceptions (try/catch/throw).

Quote from [gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_exceptions.html)

> Before detailing the library support for -fno-exceptions, first a
>   passing note on the things lost when this flag is used: it will break
>   exceptions trying to pass through code compiled with -fno-exceptions
>   whether or not that code has any try or catch constructs. **If you might
>   have some code that throws, you shouldn't use -fno-exceptions. If you
>   have some code that uses try or catch, you shouldn't use
>   -fno-exceptions.**

Comment: Thanks I didnt knew that. Then where to use -fno-exceptions ?? Just to avoid throwing exception by some other code like div by 0 ?? I just saw 
#if __cpp_exceptions
# define __try      try
# define __catch(X) catch(X)
# define __throw_exception_again throw
#else
# define __try      if (true)
# define __catch(X) if (false)
# define __throw_exception_again
#endif
 in the docs

Comment: @Kiran simple answer is never. But if you need - only with code, that don't throw exceptions. DIV by 0 is no exception. Read documentation about this flag.

Comment: I have a client code which uses exceptions all the time. And I have a test setup where the compilation flag is set to -fno-exception and I cann't control flags there.  I need to integrate client lib into my overall project. How to deal with this situation??

Comment: @Kiran Your two options are to change either the client or your test setup.

Comment: Using `-fno-exceptions` is a way to have useful branch coverage data, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43726240/1945549.

Answer (score 6):

You can't compile a program with this flag if you throw exceptions in your own code. The `-fno-exceptions` flag does the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7249442/1750757):

> 1. All exception handling in STL libraries are removed; throws are replaced with abort() calls
> 2. Stack unwind data and code is removed. This saves some code space, and may make register allocation marginally easier for the compiler (but I doubt it'll have much performance impact). Notably, however, if an exception is thrown, and the library tries to unwind through `-fno-exceptions` code, it will abort at that point, as there is no unwind data.
>
> This will, effectively, turn all exceptions into `abort()`s, as you would like. Note, however, that you will not be allowed to throw - any actual `throw`s or `catch`s in your code will result in a compile-time error.

Answer (score 5):

I found a  workaround. Except for the "e" in the catch block the code can be rewritten like

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
  __try
  {
    __throw_exception_again 20;
  }
  __catch (int e)
  {
    cout << "An exception occurred." << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

and can be compiled with

```
g++ throw.cc -o out -fno-exceptions.
```

Comment: `__try` and `__catch` are macros that convert to `if (true)` and `if (false)`, respectively, if CPP exceptions are disabled. Your try/catch blocks are thus not doing anything in this case.