# Different branch coverage generated by GCC/GCOV for function using throw() / noexcept

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, gcov, lcov

I would like to understand the branches generated by GCC compiler when using `noexcept` or `throw()` for marking non-throwing function. I know the differences between `noexcept` and `throw()`, but cannot figure out what are the additional branches defined when using `throw()` instead of `noexcept` and how to improve the coverage to have 100% of branch coverage?

Code snippet of tested example class:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() noexcept :
        iThrowFlag(false)
    {}

    void non_throwing_method() noexcept
    {
        try
        {
            throwing_method();
        }
        catch (...)
        {
        }
    }

    void throwing_method()
    {
        if (iThrowFlag)
        {
            throw std::exception();
        }
    }

public:
    bool iThrowFlag;
};
```

There are 2 test cases defined, both passing:

1. Verification if `non_throwing_method` completes when underlying `throwing_method` is not throwing,
2. Verification if `non_throwing_method` completes when underlying `throwing_method` is throwing any exception.

Below is the coverage report generated by GCC/GCOV for above code, all the lines and branches are covered (4/4 branches covered):

```
        -:    0:Source:myclass.hh
        -:    0:Graph:main.gcno
        -:    0:Data:main.gcda
        -:    0:Runs:1
        -:    0:Programs:1
        -:    1:#include <iostream>
        -:    2:#include <string>
        -:    3:
        -:    4:using namespace std;
        -:    5:
        -:    6:class MyClass
        -:    7:{
        -:    8:public:
function _ZN7MyClassC2Ev called 2 returned 100% blocks executed 100%
        2:    9:    MyClass() noexcept :
        2:   10:        iThrowFlag(false)
        2:   11:    {}
        -:   12:
function _ZN7MyClass19non_throwing_methodEv called 2 returned 100% blocks executed 100%
        2:   13:    void non_throwing_method() noexcept
        -:   14:    {
        -:   15:        try
        -:   16:        {
        2:   17:            throwing_method();
call    0 returned 100%
branch  1 taken 50% (fallthrough)
branch  2 taken 50% (throw)
        -:   18:        }
        1:   19:        catch (...)
call    0 returned 100%
        -:   20:        {
        -:   21:        }
        2:   22:    }
        -:   23:
function _ZN7MyClass15throwing_methodEv called 2 returned 50% blocks executed 100%
        2:   24:    void throwing_method()
        -:   25:    {
        2:   26:        if (iThrowFlag)
branch  0 taken 50% (fallthrough)
branch  1 taken 50%
        -:   27:        {
        1:   28:            throw std::exception();
call    0 returned 100%
call    1 returned 100%
call    2 returned 0%
        -:   29:        }
        1:   30:    }
        -:   31:
        -:   32:public:
        -:   33:    bool iThrowFlag;
        -:   34:};
```

As target platform does not support C++11 and `noexcept`, it was exchanged with `throw()` specifier as below:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() throw() :
        iThrowFlag(false)
    {}

    void non_throwing_method() throw()
    {
        try
        {
            throwing_method();
        }
        catch (...)
        {
        }
    }

    void throwing_method()
    {
        if (iThrowFlag)
        {
            throw std::exception();
        }
    }

public:
    bool iThrowFlag;
};
```

Below the GCOV output with examined branches (5/8). Code with `throw()` generates additional 4 branches, which are quite hard to understand and to cover by testing:

```
        -:    0:Source:myclass.hh
        -:    0:Graph:main.gcno
        -:    0:Data:main.gcda
        -:    0:Runs:1
        -:    0:Programs:1
        -:    1:#include <iostream>
        -:    2:#include <string>
        -:    3:
        -:    4:using namespace std;
        -:    5:
        -:    6:class MyClass
        -:    7:{
        -:    8:public:
function _ZN7MyClassC2Ev called 2 returned 100% blocks executed 100%
        2:    9:    MyClass() throw() :
        2:   10:        iThrowFlag(false)
        2:   11:    {}
        -:   12:
function _ZN7MyClass19non_throwing_methodEv called 2 returned 100% blocks executed 75%
        2:   13:    void non_throwing_method() throw()
        -:   14:    {
        -:   15:        try
        -:   16:        {
        2:   17:            throwing_method();
call    0 returned 100%
branch  1 taken 50% (fallthrough)
branch  2 taken 50% (throw)
        -:   18:        }
        1:   19:        catch (...)
call    0 returned 100%
call    1 returned 100%
branch  2 taken 100% (fallthrough)
branch  3 taken 0% (throw)
branch  4 never executed
branch  5 never executed
call    6 never executed
        -:   20:        {
        -:   21:        }
        2:   22:    }
        -:   23:
function _ZN7MyClass15throwing_methodEv called 2 returned 50% blocks executed 100%
        2:   24:    void throwing_method()
        -:   25:    {
        2:   26:        if (iThrowFlag)
branch  0 taken 50% (fallthrough)
branch  1 taken 50%
        -:   27:        {
        1:   28:            throw std::exception();
call    0 returned 100%
call    1 returned 100%
call    2 returned 0%
        -:   29:        }
        1:   30:    }
        -:   31:
        -:   32:public:
        -:   33:    bool iThrowFlag;
        -:   34:};
```

Test cases are below (to have full details about the case):

```
void test1()
{
    MyClass lObj;
    lObj.non_throwing_method();
}

void test2()
{
    MyClass lObj;
    lObj.iThrowFlag = true;
    lObj.non_throwing_method();
    lObj.iThrowFlag = false;
}
```

I would appreciate if someone have an answer/explanation for described behavior.

EDIT:
Additionally attached assembly code (only code of function: `non_throwing_method1 to compare).

With noexcept:

```
_ZN7MyClass19non_throwing_methodEv:
.LFB1253:
    .loc 2 13 0
    .cfi_startproc
    .cfi_personality 0x3,__gxx_personality_v0
    .cfi_lsda 0x3,.LLSDA1253
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
    movq    __gcov0._ZN7MyClass19non_throwing_methodEv(%rip), %rax
    addq    $1, %rax
    movq    %rax, __gcov0._ZN7MyClass19non_throwing_methodEv(%rip)
    .loc 2 17 0
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
.LEHB0:
    call    _ZN7MyClass15throwing_methodEv
.LEHE0:
    movq    __gcov0._ZN7MyClass19non_throwing_methodEv+8(%rip), %rax
    addq    $1, %rax
    movq    %rax, __gcov0._ZN7MyClass19non_throwing_methodEv+8(%rip)
    .loc 2 22 0
    jmp .L7
.L6:
    movq    %rax, %rdx
    movq    __gcov0._ZN7MyClass19non_throwing_methodEv+16(%rip), %rax
    addq    $1, %rax
    movq    %rax, __gcov0._ZN7MyClass19non_throwing_methodEv+16(%rip)
    .loc 2 19 0
    movq    %rdx, %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    __cxa_begin_catch
    movq    __gcov0._ZN7MyClass19non_throwing_methodEv+24(%rip), %rax
    addq    $1, %rax
    movq    %rax, __gcov0._ZN7MyClass19non_throwing_methodEv+24(%rip)
    call    __cxa_end_catch
    movq    __gcov0._ZN7MyClass19non_throwing_methodEv+32(%rip), %rax
    addq    $1, %rax
    movq    %rax, __gcov0._ZN7MyClass19non_throwing_methodEv+32(%rip)
.L7:
    .loc 2 22 0
    nop
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1253:
    .globl  __gxx_personality_v0
    .section    .gcc_except_table._ZN7MyClass19non_throwing_methodEv,"aG",@progbits,_ZN7MyClass19non_throwing_methodEv,comdat
    .align 4
.LLSDA1253:
    .byte   0xff
    .byte   0x3
    .uleb128 .LLSDATT1253-.LLSDATTD1253
.LLSDATTD1253:
    .byte   0x1
    .uleb128 .LLSDACSE1253-.LLSDACSB1253
.LLSDACSB1253:
    .uleb128 .LEHB0-.LFB1253
    .uleb128 .LEHE0-.LEHB0
    .uleb128 .L6-.LFB1253
    .uleb128 0x1
.LLSDACSE1253:
    .byte   0x1
    .byte   0
    .align 4
    .long   0

.LLSDATT1253:
    .section    .text._ZN7MyClass19non_throwing_methodEv,"axG",@progbits,_ZN7MyClass19non_throwing_methodEv,comdat
    .size   _ZN7MyClass19non_throwing_methodEv, .-_ZN7MyClass19non_throwing_methodEv
    .section    .text._ZN7MyClass15throwing_methodEv,"axG",@progbits,_ZN7MyClass15throwing_methodEv,comdat
    .align 2
    .weak   _ZN7MyClass15throwing_methodEv
    .type   _ZN7MyClass15throwing_methodEv, @function
```

With throw():

```
_ZN7MyClass19non_throwing_methodEv:
.LFB1253:
    .loc 2 13 0
    .cfi_startproc
    .cfi_personality 0x3,__gxx_personality_v0
    .cfi_lsda 0x3,.LLSDA1253
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
    movq    __gcov0._ZN7MyClass19non_throwing_methodEv(%rip), %rax
    addq    $1, %rax
    movq    %rax, __gcov0._ZN7MyClass19non_throwing_methodEv(%rip)
    .loc 2 17 0
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
.LEHB0:
    call    _ZN7MyClass15throwing_methodEv
.LEHE0:
    movq    __gcov0._ZN7MyClass19non_throwing_methodEv+8(%rip), %rax
    addq    $1, %rax
    movq    %rax, __gcov0._ZN7MyClass19non_throwing_methodEv+8(%rip)
    .loc 2 22 0
    jmp .L3
.L8:
    movq    %rax, %rdx
    movq    __gcov0._ZN7MyClass19non_throwing_methodEv+16(%rip), %rax
    addq    $1, %rax
    movq    %rax, __gcov0._ZN7MyClass19non_throwing_methodEv+16(%rip)
    .loc 2 19 0
    movq    %rdx, %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    __cxa_begin_catch
    movq    __gcov0._ZN7MyClass19non_throwing_methodEv+24(%rip), %rax
    addq    $1, %rax
    movq    %rax, __gcov0._ZN7MyClass19non_throwing_methodEv+24(%rip)
.LEHB1:
    call    __cxa_end_catch
.LEHE1:
    movq    __gcov0._ZN7MyClass19non_throwing_methodEv+32(%rip), %rax
    addq    $1, %rax
    movq    %rax, __gcov0._ZN7MyClass19non_throwing_methodEv+32(%rip)
    .loc 2 22 0
    jmp .L3
.L9:
    cmpq    $-1, %rdx
    je  .L7
    movq    __gcov0._ZN7MyClass19non_throwing_methodEv+48(%rip), %rdx
    addq    $1, %rdx
    movq    %rdx, __gcov0._ZN7MyClass19non_throwing_methodEv+48(%rip)
    movq    %rax, %rdi
.LEHB2:
    call    _Unwind_Resume
.L7:
    movq    __gcov0._ZN7MyClass19non_throwing_methodEv+40(%rip), %rdx
    addq    $1, %rdx
    movq    %rdx, __gcov0._ZN7MyClass19non_throwing_methodEv+40(%rip)
    .loc 2 13 0
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    __cxa_call_unexpected
.LEHE2:
.L3:
    .loc 2 22 0
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1253:
    .globl  __gxx_personality_v0
    .section    .gcc_except_table._ZN7MyClass19non_throwing_methodEv,"aG",@progbits,_ZN7MyClass19non_throwing_methodEv,comdat
    .align 4
.LLSDA1253:
    .byte   0xff
    .byte   0x3
    .uleb128 .LLSDATT1253-.LLSDATTD1253
.LLSDATTD1253:
    .byte   0x1
    .uleb128 .LLSDACSE1253-.LLSDACSB1253
.LLSDACSB1253:
    .uleb128 .LEHB0-.LFB1253
    .uleb128 .LEHE0-.LEHB0
    .uleb128 .L8-.LFB1253
    .uleb128 0x1
    .uleb128 .LEHB1-.LFB1253
    .uleb128 .LEHE1-.LEHB1
    .uleb128 .L9-.LFB1253
    .uleb128 0x3
    .uleb128 .LEHB2-.LFB1253
    .uleb128 .LEHE2-.LEHB2
    .uleb128 0
    .uleb128 0
.LLSDACSE1253:
    .byte   0x1
    .byte   0
    .byte   0x7f
    .byte   0
    .align 4
    .long   0

.LLSDATT1253:
    .byte   0
    .section    .text._ZN7MyClass19non_throwing_methodEv,"axG",@progbits,_ZN7MyClass19non_throwing_methodEv,comdat
    .size   _ZN7MyClass19non_throwing_methodEv, .-_ZN7MyClass19non_throwing_methodEv
    .section    .text._ZN7MyClass15throwing_methodEv,"axG",@progbits,_ZN7MyClass15throwing_methodEv,comdat
    .align 2
    .weak   _ZN7MyClass15throwing_methodEv
    .type   _ZN7MyClass15throwing_methodEv, @function
```

Comment: While understanding the different branches is not that easy you may use the filter approach: for systems that don't implement C++11 you can filter the result files from lcov before feeding them to gcov, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43726240/5027456 for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that I'm gonna answer my own question after a while.

The difference between `throw()` and `noexcept` (since C++11 until C++17) is quite big.

At runtime, if an exception leaves function marked as
`throw()` the call stack is unwound to function's caller, then `std::unexpected` is called to execute unexpected handler and finally (default behaviour) the program is terminated by `std::terminate`.

With the C++11 noexcept runtime behavior is slightly different: the call stack is only *possibly* unwound before program execution is terminated. No `std::unexpected` called. Usually compilers just call `std::terminate` without unwinding.

And that's it, this is why `throw()` and `noexcept` functions generate different assembly code and the code coverage tools measure different results.

Fortunately, since C++17 there will be no surprises any more, as dynamic exception specification is deprecated and removed from standard, while `throw()` specification remains valid, but it is same as `noexcept(true)`.